# Updating SQL Server tables through BizTalk's SQL adapter

Tags: sql, biztalk, adapter

We are getting data from an external website via BizTalk 2009. Several SQL Server tables are being updated with this data through a SQL adapter and SOAP. So the Visual Studio 2008 project that already updates tables has schemas and mappings. I need to add 3 columns to each SQL Server table so these columns are also updated with data from that website (those columns are already in the website and the SQL Server tables just need to be updated with that data).

I can add column to the actual SQL tables (using ALTER TABLE), but how would I actually retrieve data from that website through the Visual Server project so these tables are updated? Do I add columns to the schema?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the three fields to the message schema your SQL data is mapped onto.

Also update the SQL statement which is executed inside your sql adapter settings to return the new columns.

**UPDATE**

The sql statement executed in the adapter can be found in BizTalk admin:
Application -> Receive Locations -> SQL Receive Location properties -> Configure -> SQL Command

[image: SQL Receive Location properties]

In my case this is a stored procedure call so I would need to adjust the returned dataset of the stored procedure.

Comment: I am unable to add any fields or nodes to my xsd schema. When I right-click on a field and select "Insert Schema Node", all options are greyed out.

Comment: Also, how do I find the the SQL statement which is executed inside my sql adapter settings? Thanks.

Comment: OK I figured out how to add fields to the message schema (by adding nodes to the xsd file the schema is imported from). How do I find the the SQL statement which is executed inside my sql adapter settings? Thanks!

Comment: No worries. If this has sorted your problem please mark my answer as such. Many thanks